# Convert vb.net to linq lambda

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

How do you translate the underlying code into linq lambda?

```
For Each prize As FidelityPrize In listFidelityPrize
    If Not prize.IsOldCampaign Then
        If prize.Threshold.HasValue Then
            thresholdTotal = prize.Threshold.Value
            ok = True
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: yes, also how do you get the minimum threshold value in the list?

Comment: If you need to get multiple values from a list, then LINQ is probably not the best choice. Don't just try to use LINQ because you can. Use it when it makes your life easier.

Comment: Firstly, why do you have two nested `If` statements instead of one with an `AndAlso` operator? As for the question, you can call `LastOrDefault` to get the last item that matches those criteria in one line, then test whether the result is `Nothing` and, if not, do basically the same thing you are inside you `If` statement now. There's not really a logical way to do all that in a single line of code, if that's what you were hoping for.

Comment: is the threasholdtotal suppose to hold the sum of all threashold values if they are not part of old campain?

Comment: It's a misunderstanding that the shorter code is, the beter it is. Forcing the use of lambda or linq without having any advantage of it, just to make it look tight, will mostly result in less readable code. There is nothing wrong with using a simple (readable) foreach.